# how to get checked rows QtableWidget

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, qtablewidget

I have this code. I want to delete any row **whose tick was active** when clicked the delete button

```
from main import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from  PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

def set_cell_elements(rows, l):
    ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(rows))
    ui.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(rows)
    ui.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
    ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    for r in range(0, len(l)):
        for i in range (0, len(l[r])) :
            text = l[r][i]
            ui.tableWidget.setItem(r, i, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(text)))
            ui.tableWidget.item(r, i).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            item = ui.tableWidget.item(r, 0)
            item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            item.checkState()
            table_ = ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
            table_.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

def delete_button():
    pass

import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#=====================
rows = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
l = [['Wade', 'Wade', 'Seth', 'Ivan', 'Riley'],
        ['Gilbert', 'Jorge', 'Dan', 'Brian', 'Roberto'],
        ['Ramon', 'Liam', 'Miles', 'Nathaniel', 'Lewis'],
        ['Ethan', 'Milton', 'Joshua', 'Claude', 'Glen'],
        ['Harvey', 'Blake', 'Antonio', 'Connor', 'Julian'],
        ['Aidan', 'Harold', 'Conner', 'Peter', 'Hunter']]

set_cell_elements(rows, l)
ui.delete_button.clicked.connect(delete_button)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I do not have a solution to get rows whose tick is active, can you help me !? Please

Comment: For future reference, please don't delete a post just because it was closed (closed doesn't mean deleted, they can be opened again), instead *edit* it and provide what's requested.

Comment: You're already using `checkState()` (even if it's doing nothing there), why don't you use it in the `delete_button` function?

Comment: If the row check is enabled, the output of checkState () is 2, but when I tried to delete the data in the same way, the output was 0. I am a beginner, I could not solve the problem, I said maybe the way is wrong and there is another solution -@musicamante

Comment: how have you "tried to delete the data"? Also, you're saying that you want to remove a row, not delete the data, those are two different things. Whatever you tried, please [edit] your post and show us, so that we can properly guide you, explain what you did wrong and show you possible solutions.

Comment: Oh, I apologize. My mistake was that I wrote the code like this
if item.checkstate () is True:
Because its value is equal to 2, this condition does not apply and I was wrong here

I always thought he assumed numbers greater than 0 to be true.

Comment: that's why it's important to always provide a [mre] of your code, even when it doesn't "work" (we must be able to reproduce *your problem*). To be precise, the checkstate doesn't return "literally" 2, but the `QtCore.Qt.Checked` enum, which equals to 2. In any case, you could have just done this: `if item.checkState():` which is more or less «verify weather the result of `item.checkState()` is *anything* but a "null" value» (including but not limited to `None`, 0, False or an empty object like a list or a tuple).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to StackOverflow! There are some missing information in your question to be able to help you with your problem. I can only guess the missing part of your code.

I guess that you have used Qt Designer to create graphically your UI. I will suppose that you UI looks like that:

[image: Image representation of the guessed UI]

When compiled it gives:

### main.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Ui_MainWindow.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(19, 16, 761, 521))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setSizeConstraint(QtWidgets.QLayout.SetMaximumSize)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.delete_button = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.delete_button.setObjectName("delete_button")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.delete_button)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.tableWidget.setBaseSize(QtCore.QSize(0, 0))
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(6)
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 24))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.delete_button.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete selected rows"))
```

The minimal changes solution would be:

### Solution 1.py

```py
from main import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets
from  PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

def set_cell_elements(rows, l):
    ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(rows))
    ui.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(rows)
    ui.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
    ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    for r in range(0, len(l)):
        for i in range (0, len(l[r])) :
            text = l[r][i]
            ui.tableWidget.setItem(r, i, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(text)))
            ui.tableWidget.item(r, i).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            item = ui.tableWidget.item(r, 0)
            item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
            item.checkState()
            table_ = ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
            table_.setSectionResizeMode(i, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)

def delete_button():
    for r in range(ui.tableWidget.rowCount(), 0, -1):
        item = ui.tableWidget.item(r - 1, 0)
        if item.checkState() == Qt.Checked:
            ui.tableWidget.removeRow(r - 1)

import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
#=====================
rows = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']
l = [['Wade', 'Wade', 'Seth', 'Ivan', 'Riley'],
        ['Gilbert', 'Jorge', 'Dan', 'Brian', 'Roberto'],
        ['Ramon', 'Liam', 'Miles', 'Nathaniel', 'Lewis'],
        ['Ethan', 'Milton', 'Joshua', 'Claude', 'Glen'],
        ['Harvey', 'Blake', 'Antonio', 'Connor', 'Julian'],
        ['Aidan', 'Harold', 'Conner', 'Peter', 'Hunter']]

set_cell_elements(rows, l)
ui.delete_button.clicked.connect(delete_button)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

But there can be some more cleanup and simplification to your code:

### Solution 2.py

```py
from main import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

def set_cell_elements(row_headers, data_body):
    ui.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(row_headers))
    ui.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(row_headers)
    ui.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
    ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

    for (row_number, current_row) in enumerate(data_body):
        for (column_number, current_text) in enumerate(current_row):
            ui.tableWidget.setItem(
                row_number, column_number, 
                QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(current_text))
            )
            ui.tableWidget.item(row_number, column_number).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
            row_header = ui.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
            row_header.setSectionResizeMode(column_number, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
        item = ui.tableWidget.item(row_number, 0)
        item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
        item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
 
def delete_button_action():    
    for current_row in range(ui.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, -1, -1):
        first_item = ui.tableWidget.item(current_row, 0)
        state_current_row = first_item.checkState()
        if state_current_row == Qt.Checked:
            ui.tableWidget.removeRow(current_row)
    
import sys
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = Ui_MainWindow()
ui.setupUi(MainWindow)

row_headers = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
data_body = (
    ('Wade', 'Wade', 'Seth', 'Ivan', 'Riley'),
    ('Gilbert', 'Jorge', 'Dan', 'Brian', 'Roberto'),
    ('Ethan', 'Milton', 'Joshua', 'Claude', 'Glen'),
    ('Ramon', 'Liam', 'Miles', 'Nathaniel', 'Lewis'),
    ('Harvey', 'Blake', 'Antonio', 'Connor', 'Julian'),
    ('Aidan', 'Harold', 'Conner', 'Peter', 'Hunter')
)

set_cell_elements(row_headers, data_body)
ui.delete_button.clicked.connect(delete_button_action)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

But you could code this in a more object-oriented way. That way, as long as you provide the containing widget and its initial data, you can plug it anywhere in your UI and it will take of itself:

### Solution 3.py

```py
import sys
from main import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt

class Simple_table_editor(Ui_MainWindow):

    def __init__(self, parent, row_headers, initial_data):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(parent)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(row_headers))
        self.tableWidget.setVerticalHeaderLabels(row_headers)
        self.tableWidget.verticalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignVCenter)
        self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setDefaultAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)

        for (row_number, current_row) in enumerate(initial_data):
            for (column_number, current_text) in enumerate(current_row):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(
                    row_number, column_number, 
                    QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(str(current_text))
                )
                self.tableWidget.item(row_number, column_number).setTextAlignment(Qt.AlignCenter)
                row_header = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader()
                row_header.setSectionResizeMode(column_number, QtWidgets.QHeaderView.ResizeToContents)
            item = self.tableWidget.item(row_number, 0)
            item.setFlags(Qt.ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt.ItemIsEnabled)
            item.setCheckState(Qt.Unchecked)
        
        self.delete_button.clicked.connect(self.delete_button_action)

    def delete_button_action(self):    
        for current_row in range(self.tableWidget.rowCount() - 1, -1, -1):
            first_item = self.tableWidget.item(current_row, 0)
            state_current_row = first_item.checkState()
            if state_current_row == Qt.Checked:
                self.tableWidget.removeRow(current_row)

row_headers = ('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f')
data_body = (
    ('Wade', 'Wade', 'Seth', 'Ivan', 'Riley'),
    ('Gilbert', 'Jorge', 'Dan', 'Brian', 'Roberto'),
    ('Ethan', 'Milton', 'Joshua', 'Claude', 'Glen'),
    ('Ramon', 'Liam', 'Miles', 'Nathaniel', 'Lewis'),
    ('Harvey', 'Blake', 'Antonio', 'Connor', 'Julian'),
    ('Aidan', 'Harold', 'Conner', 'Peter', 'Hunter')
)

app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
table_editor = Simple_table_editor(MainWindow, row_headers, data_body)
MainWindow.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

---

If my guesses are wrong and you meant to do something else, please give us more detail.